# select a value in all listbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to create a jquery function which select the same value in all listbox

I'm looking for something like this but it doesn't work

```
var myArray = $("#form :select");
myArray.each(function(item) {
        item.val(value);
});
```

Comment: `$("#form select").val(value)` would suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `.val()` directly, not need to iterate.

```
$("#form select").val(value)
```

```js
$("#form select").val(2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form'>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Another question, in some cases, I'd like to add a filter : only the controls with a specific name. Is it possible ?

Comment: @P.Sohm, Go through above link and only with specific name `$("#form select[name='someName']")`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
$('#select-all').click(function(){
  $('form select').val('3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    <option val="5">5</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="button" id="select-all" value="Select 3" />
```